# Build trigger task in Azure Devops not getting executed for template based pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, build-triggers

I have Azure Devops pipeline A to trigger another pipeline (pipeline B in the same project). Pipeline B has some object type parameters as below

```
parameters:
  envList:
  - production
  - dr
  alertList:
  - alertnumber: 01
    alertrulename: xxxxxxxxx
    appname: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    query: >
      union AppExceptions, AppRequests
      | where AppRoleName == "xxxxxx"
    alertDescription: xxxxxx
    frequencyInMinutes: 10
    timeWindowInMinutes: 10
    severity: 1
    operator: GreaterThan
    threshold: 40
    autoMitigate: true
    enabled: true
    todeploy: yes
```

here in each parameter "alertList", I have a flag "todeploy: yes" to decide whether the particular alert need to be triggered in a particular envt, as below and this settings working fine for pipeline B.

```
stages:
  - ${{ each environment in parameters.envList }}:  
    - stage: BuilD_ARM_LogAnalytic_Artifact_${{ environment }}
      jobs:
        - ${{ each alert in parameters.alertList }}:
          - ${{ if eq(alert.todeploy, 'yes') }}:
            - job: BuilD_ARM_LogAnalytic_Artifact_${{ environment }}_${{ alert.alertnumber }}
              displayName: '${{ alert.alertRuleName }}'
              condition: eq('${{ alert.todeploy }}', 'yes')
```

But when I used Pipeline A to trigger the pipeline B,

```
 steps:
 - task: TriggerBuild@4
   inputs:
     definitionIsInCurrentTeamProject: true
     buildDefinition: 'pipelineA'
     queueBuildForUserThatTriggeredBuild: true
     ignoreSslCertificateErrors: false
     useSameSourceVersion: false
     useCustomSourceVersion: false
     useSameBranch: false
     waitForQueuedBuildsToFinish: false
     storeInEnvironmentVariable: false
     templateParameters: 'alertList: [todeploy: yes]'
     authenticationMethod: 'Personal Access Token'
     password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     enableBuildInQueueCondition: false
     dependentOnSuccessfulBuildCondition: false
     dependentOnFailedBuildCondition: false
     checkbuildsoncurrentbranch: false
     failTaskIfConditionsAreNotFulfilled: false
```

The Pipeline B is not getting executed and error as below

```
Team Project: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Using current Collection Url
Server URL: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Using following Authentication Method: Personal Access Token
Using Personal Access Token
Provided team project was guid.
Context is Build - using Build Environment Variables
Build shall be triggered for same user that triggered current build: xxxxxx
Will trigger build with following template parameters: alertList: [todeploy: yes]
Found parameter alertList with value: [todeploy: yes]
Error during request (1/5)
Error message: Error: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.
Will wait 1 seconds before retrying request...
Error during request (2/5)
Error message: Error: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.
Will wait 2 seconds before retrying request...
Error during request (3/5)
Error message: Error: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.
Will wait 4 seconds before retrying request...
Error during request (4/5)
Error message: Error: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.
Will wait 8 seconds before retrying request...
Error during request (5/5)
Error message: Error: Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Request failed after 5 tries - see error messages in the log
```

Not sure how to pass these parameters both `envt: dr` and `alertList` with flag (todeploy: yes) from pipeline A